# Python Random Number Guessing Game (cant get the average guess right)

Tags: python

I'm newly introduced to Python but I am now currently stuck with this code of mine where I just can't get the average guess game per game to work. If I could receive some help from you guys that'll be great! I would also love to hear any constructive feedback if there's any. Thank you!!

```
# A robust number-guessing game with hinting.
import random

total_guess = 0
num_games = 0
num_guesses = 0 

print("Welcome to Guessing Game!")
print()
reply = input("Are you ready to play (Y or N)?").upper()
while reply != "Y" and reply != "N":   
print("Invalid response")
reply = input("Another game (Y or N)? ").upper()

while reply == "Y": 
# pick a random number from 0 to 100 (both inclusive)
# There is no error in the line below, which is 
# equivalent to 
# number = random.randint(0, 100)
    number = random.randrange(0, 101)

# make it different from number so that it goes into loop
    guess = number + 1 

    while guess != number :
        guess = int(input("Your guess (0 - 100)? "))

        num_guesses += 1

        if guess < number :
            print("Your guess is too low")
        elif guess > number :
            print("Your guess is too high")
        else:
            print("Bingo!")        

    # collect the statistics to calculate average guess per game
        total_guess += num_guesses
        num_games += 1

    print("You got it right in " + str(num_guesses) + " tries.")
    num_guesses = 0
    print()
    reply = input("Another game (Y or N)? ").upper()

    while reply != "Y" and reply != "N":   
        print("Invalid response")
        reply = input("Another game (Y or N)? ").upper()

    print("Your average guess per game is", total_guess/num_games)
```

Comment: First advice: use proper *indentations*.

Comment: Please include how it is working now (error message? wrong output?) and how you'd like it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was not properly indented.

```
import random

total_guess = 0
num_games = 0
num_guesses = 0 

print("Welcome to Guessing Game!")
print()
reply = input("Are you ready to play (Y or N)?").upper()
while reply != "Y" and reply != "N":   
  print("Invalid response")
  reply = input("Another game (Y or N)? ").upper()

while reply == "Y": 
    number = random.randrange(0, 11)

# make it different from number so that it goes into loop
    guess = number + 1 

    while guess != number :
        guess = int(input("Your guess (0 - 100)? "))

        num_guesses += 1

        if guess < number :
            print("Your guess is too low")
        elif guess > number :
            print("Your guess is too high")
        else:
            print("Bingo!")        

    # collect the statistics to calculate average guess per game
    total_guess += num_guesses
    num_games += 1

    print("You got it right in " + str(num_guesses) + " tries.")
    num_guesses = 0
    print()
    reply = input("Another game (Y or N)? ").upper()
    while reply != "Y" and reply != "N":   
        print("Invalid response")
        reply = input("Another game (Y or N)? ").upper()
    print("Your average guess per game is", total_guess/num_games)
```